# USB 3.0 driver for asus zenbook ux303ub windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, zenbook

I downgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 7 64b, but there are no drivers for Windows 7, so I installed all drivers for Windows 10 and everything works except for USB ports. Could you please help me..is there so driver e.g. for some other device which I could use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This notebook uses one of regular "Skylake" chipsets with i5/i7 6-th generation CPU. The same chipset (not sure which one H110/H170/Z170/B150/Q150/Q170 is used in the notebook) can be found in numerous ASUS motherboards. ASUS does provide USB 3.0 drivers for Windows 7, [see an example here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z170M-PLUS/HelpDesk_Download/). It should work.